# Java: How can I get JSON value from a script tag?

Tags: java, json

My goal is to get JSON value from a script tag from a web page. The tricky part is the javaScript tag contains lot of functions as well as JSON array. I was able to convert the entire script in string format through jsoup but I'm not sure how to get value of the JSON variable.

here is my Java code

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").timeout(1000).get();
    Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
    for (Element element :scriptElements ){                
        for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
          System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
          }
    }`
```

script tag

`<script type="text/javascript"> x.y = x.y ||{}; if(typeof x.y.z==='hello'){
x.y={name:'myName'||'', id:'123', a:function(app,eve,json),1);}}, b:function()....}}</script>`

Here I want to get the value of name and id

Comment: (That's not JSON.)

Comment: If you know the code will always be structured like that then you can use simple string functions to find and extract that value.

Comment: How can I get the value of above variables?

Comment: Use `indexOf()` and `substring()`, both of which are explained here... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm

Comment: Thanks @Archer and user2864740

Answer (score -1):

As well as using a substring you may also want to consider parsing the javascript (it is javascript not json) with a tool like http://www.antlr.org/